# Codeigniter htaccess redirect to non-www

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter.I want to redirect all users from www to non-www.
I mean if user does a request to `http://www.example.com` it should be redirected to `http://example.com` or `http://www.example.com/url/1/2` to `http://example.com/url/1/2`

How can I achive this ?

**My htacess code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why did you remove this line RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [QSA,L] ? I don't want to use index.php in url.

Comment: I am getting 404 error.For this url: example.com/abc

Comment: make sure your `base_url` also `example.com`

Comment: Yes I did but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    #for redirect non www to www

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    #for redirect www to non www

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Also for http to https redirect

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```